# Why PUT request with FormData object appends not sent to Laravel controller?

Tags: javascript, laravel, request, axios, form-data

Why I can't sent FormData object values to my Laravel application

**Javascript code:**

```
console.log("Sending start...")
for (var value of company.values()) {
    console.log(value); 
}
this.$axios.put(url, company)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

**Response preview:**

[image]

**Laravel controller:**

```
public function update(Request $request, Company $company)
{
    return response()->json($request->all());
}
```

Where I've any error?

Comment: may be you not taking `company.values()` in axios put method.

Comment: How I can take it then? @JinalSomaiya

Comment: replace `company` to `company.values()` in axios put method.

Comment: I'll sent to server multiple form data request (with file). Then when I replace `company` to `company.values()` will be sent files? @JinalSomaiya

Comment: please try it. @AndreasHunter

Comment: Return error @JinalSomaiya `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: company.values is not a function`

Comment: Could paste the out of console.log(company)

Comment: Here is [screenshot](https://imgur.com/16xTQmy) @JinalSomaiya

Comment: Currently Laravel does not support put request. Could you try using post just to see if its received in backend - Laravel

Comment: Why your think what Laravel doesn't support `PUT` request? When I sent non `FormData` object (default) request, it's work successfully for me. But when try sent `FormData` request then it's not work.

Comment: It does work in Laravel. However, when using ```FormData``` you have to spoof the ```post``` request: ```formData.append('_method', 'PUT')```

Comment: It's also doesn't work to me @DinoNumić

Comment: @AndreasHunter Can you copy the code of how you create your form data object

Comment: [Here](http://snippi.com/s/kub6ww4) the my `FormData` object @DinoNumić

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to trick the Laravel framework by sending a `POST` request with `axios` assigning method type as `PUT` to `FormData` object.

**Code:**

```
// Lets create FormData object
let data = new FormData()
data.append('_method', 'PUT')
// ...........................
// other your appends here...

// Axios request
this.$axios.post(url, data)
  .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
  })
```

After checking, let me know about the result of the code :)

Comment: related discussion [1](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13457#issuecomment-239451567)